# Stuck during upgrade to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my 18.04 LST system to 20.04 and the upgrade has got stuck, the cursor is frozen and there is no reaction to anything at all. I am unable to open the terminal.

Should I force it to reboot? The system is a Dell Inspiron with Ubuntu preinstalled.

Thank you

Comment: You can force reboot, but that might corrupt the installation. If it does, you can perform a clean installation of 20.04 later on.

Answer (score 1):

My solution: I did force reboot. Boot in using an older kernel in recovery mode. In the menu displayed I chose first  'dpkg-repair broken packages' after a while the process finished and after rebooting I was able to enter into the upgraded version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I would force reboot and try again to see what happens providing you have a backup of everything and/or things you have are easily accessible to get back.

You could also try to simply download 20.04 from the website and create a bootdrive and install it that way to see what happens.

Let us know how it works out for you.